# How to transfer file Fast over the internet?

Tags: rsync

I need to transfer files over the internet whith a backup script that transfer my oracle database archive logs on-premisse to my other oracle server (an azure vm).
Today this script runs:

'''rsync -avz archivelogs root@oracledb2:/dst/bkp/'''

I enabled simpler encryptions in my ssh to make it lighter but I don't think it's safe.
Does anyone have any tips for me to be able to transfer safely over the network and with speed.

'''rsync -aHAXxv --numeric-ids --delete --progress -e "ssh -T -c arcfour -o Compression=no -x" [source_dir] [dest_host:/dest_dir]'''

this is fast but arfour cipher isn't safe ... soo ... what should i do ?

Comment: It depends on where the bottlenecks are in your system, and also on the CPUs involved. Do the CPUs have accelerated AES built in? If so, use that; it'll almost certainly be faster than any other encryption. Other than that, are you limited by the network bandwidth? Sending and/or receiving CPU? Sending and/or receiving disk? You'll need to experiment to see where the limits are, and what helps with that.

Comment: But what about security? Wouldn't it be unsafe to use ssh with weaker cipher? Thinking about and I am considering using netcat to make this copy and use a tcp por limited by firewall only to my secondary db on azure.